# Java applet game does not work on Macs, even though it does work on PCs

Tags: java, macos, applet, jpanel

I made a game that is based in a jpanel.  When I add the jpanel to a jframe, it works fine on both pc's and macs.

here is the class where I add the jpanel to the jframe:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Start{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      JFrame f = new JFrame("Rocks");
      f.setSize(600,500);
      f.setResizable(false);
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      Board b = new Board();
      f.add(b);
      f.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

However, when I add this jpanel to a japplet, it still works perfectly on pc's, but not on macs.  In the eclipse applet tester, the first screen paints, but it doesn't accept keyboard input to start the game.  In any browser/html page though, the game doesn't seem to load at all, and when I open the java console of chrome I see no errors.

here is the class where I add the jpanel to the japplet

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class rockAppletStart extends JApplet{

   public void init(){
      Board b;
      b = new Board();
      add(b);
      b.focus();
   }
   public void start(){}
   public void stop(){}
   public void destroy(){}
}
```

I would appreciate any help that could be offered, and I'm willing to provide more information if necessary.  I could even provide the other classes of the game, but there very long and messy, and I'd rather not unless necessary.

The applet version of the game can be found [here at gamejolt.com](http://gamejolt.com/online/games/arcade/rocks/4081/), if you feel like testing it out.  If you have a pc, it should work fine, but with a mac it won't.

** **edit** **
here you can download the .jar file of all the classes and resources.  Feel free to use the files to test out your solution yourself if you want...  Otherwise, Ill have access to a mac on Tuesday and I will test all solutions then.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18832480/Rocks_Source_file.jar

Comment: I think you will need to post the source for `Board` to allow someone to diagnose the problem.  The bug may be in `focus` (this is not a method of `JComponent`, so I assume it is your own implementation, or maybe you meant `requestFocus`) or in your `KeyListener`.

Comment: the focus method, is actually just a method in board that calls requestFocusInWindow() but I'm just going to post the jar for the whole game anyways

Comment: the link for the .jar has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JApplet` is stealing the focus from the `Board`.  To prevent it, add the following to the end of your `init()` method:

```
setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: ok. thank you.  I will test this on Tuesday and get back to you, unless I can get someone to test it for me before then.

Comment: This worked in that the game now runs perfectly in the eclipse applet viewer.  However, the game still doesnt run in an html page on macs.  Do macs ave an outdated version of java used in their browsers or what?

Comment: @Jeff: I have found that in Java preferences on Mac, if you select "run applets within the browser process",  the browser ignores the JRE version specified in the applet tag and always uses the default JRE.  OTOH if you select "run applets in their own process" it becomes flaky in Firefox (though fine in Safari & Chrome.)  The only reliable workaround I know of is to target Java 1.5 (it is rare for the default to be an earlier version than this.)

Comment: @Jeff: BTW your game *almost* works on Java 1.5.  There is an exception in the BufferedImage constructor where you create a rotated version of the ship image, which can be worked around by using the `BufferedImage(ColorModel, WritableRaster, boolean, HashTable)` constructor instead.  After that the game seems to run fine.

Comment: ok, thank you.  I wasn't getting any exceptions but ill work on fixing that then.

Comment: @finnw I'm kind of confused, when I look at the api for se 6 and s 5, they both seem to have all 3 constructors for BufferedImage().  Why do I need to use the one you suggest in order to guarantee that the applet works on 1.5, and how would I go about changing my code to accommodate the new constructor?  this might have to be a whole new question..

Comment: @Jeff, the change is in the behaviour of `BufferedImage.getType()`.  For `ship.png` it returns `TYPE_CUSTOM` in SE 5 which is not a valid type to pass to the constructor.  In SE 6 it returns `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` which can be passed to the constructor.

Comment: @Jeff, the following will work: `ColorModel srcCM = image.getColorModel(); BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(srcCM, srcCM.createCompatibleWritableRaster(w, h), image.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);`

Comment: i tried this and it still isnt working..  Its strange because I don't get any errors at all in my java console.  I have tried running it with just a html page i opened from my computer, and uploading it to gamejolt.com.  Neither worked, and neither one gave me and error in the java console. Just a white space where the game should be

Comment: @Jeff, in what browser are you seeing this problem (if it's Firefox 3 on Mac I probably won't be able to help - I have often found applets don't work there that work everywhere else.)

Comment: I have tried it with both Firefox 3.6 and Safari 4.  In both the same thing happens: white spot where the applet should be and no error in the console.  This is my applet tag of the html code if it makes any diffrence:  <applet code="rockAppletStart.class" archive="rocksapplet_final2.jar" height="490" width="590"> </applet>

Answer (score 2):

This is just a SWAG, but since Swing threading issues can often cause pernicious, unpredictable and hard to detect errors, what if you create your applet in a thread-safe manner?  i.e.,

```
public void init() {
   try {
      javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createGUI();
         }
      });
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("createGUI didn't successfully complete");
   }
}

private void createGUI() {
   Board b;
   b = new Board();
   getContentPane().add(b);
   b.focus()
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks.  Unfortunately, I don't have access to a mac until Tuesday this week.  I posted the jar with all the classes and resources if you have a mac and want to test this, haha.  Otherwise, ill test it out on Tuesday and get back to you.

Comment: It's perhaps a little premature to ask this question then if you can't test it, and neither can we since the code you've provided is not enough for an individual to be able to test and reproduce your problem. Ah well. Cheers.  Edit: Ah, I see you've posted the jar.

Comment: Haha, sorry, my fault.  I fixed the link to a jar that includes the source code.